# Using while loop to clear a canvas instead of remove

Tags: javascript, while-loop

In the following JavaScript I want to use a while loop to clear and reset a grid instead of the 'remove' function. I can't seem to modify it so it still works.

```
var height, width, color;

// When size is submitted by user, call makeGrid() 
$('#sizePicker').submit(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
height = $('#inputHeight').val();
width = $('#inputWeight').val();
makeGrid(height, width);
});


//creates grid's row and columns, r=rows, c=columns
function makeGrid(x, y) {
$('tr').remove(); //clear grid for next


for (var r = 1; r <= x; r++){
    $('#pixelCanvas').append('<tr id=table' + r + '></tr>');
    for (var c = 1; c <= y; c++) {
        $('#table' + r).append('<td></td>');
    }
}

//add and clear of colors of cells
$('td').click(function addColor(){
    color = $('#colorPicker').val();

    if($(this).attr('style')) {
        $(this).removeAttr('style')
    } else {
        $(this).attr('style', 'background-color:' +color);
    }
})
```

This is the function I know works but can't seem to implement

```
function clearGrid(){
while (canvas.firstChild){
     canvas.removeChild(canvas.firstChild);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're actually looking for `$('#pixelCanvas').empty()`

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
$('tr').remove(); //clear grid for next
```

With this

```
grid = $("#pixelCanvas")[0];
while (grid.rows.length > 0)
    grid.deleteRow(0);
```